# Keep getter function in sync with an object's current state in React/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, data-binding

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have a `Parent` class and a `Child` class.

```
export class Parent {
    properties: { x: number};
    child: Child;
    constructor() {
        this.properties = {
            x: 1
        }
        this.child = new Child(this.getX);
    }
    getX = () => {
        return this.properties.x;
    }
}

class Child {
    parent_getX:()=>string
    constructor(parent_getX:()=>string){
        this.parent_getX = parent_getX;
    }
}
```

The `Parent` class has:

- a field called `properties` which stores an number value called `x`.
- a function called `getX()` which simply pulls the value of `x` from within the `properties` object.
- a field called `child` which holds a reference to a `Child` object.

The `Child` class only receives a reference to the `Parent`'s `getX()` function.

**WHAT I WANT**

My goal is to be able to update the value of `x` and that everytime I call `child.parent_getX()` or `parent.getX()` I get the latest value of `x`.

**WHAT I'M SEEING**

I have a React component called `Example` that takes a `Parent` object with a an `x` value of 1 as initial state.

Whenever I increment this value using `setState(...)` the value of `x` is incremented but for some reason, `parent.getX()` and `parent.child.parent_getX()` always keeps returning the initial value of `x`. What can I do to keep the function in sync with the parent object?

```
export const Example = () => {

    const [parent, setParent] = useState(new Parent());

    const incrementX = ()=>{
        let newParent = { ...parent, properties: { ...parent.properties, x: parent.properties.x + 1 } }
        setParent(newParent);
    }

    return (<>
        <p>
            Parent.properties.x = {parent.properties.x}
            <br/>
            Parent.getX() = {parent.getX()}
            <br/>
            Parent.child.parent_getX() = {parent.child.parent_getX()}
        </p>
        <button onClick={incrementX}>
            Increment
        </button>
    </>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are seeing the old values is that in `incrementX()` you create a copy of the existing `Parent` instead of instantiating a new one with `new ()`. Therefore, the existing instance of `Child` (which references the old parent's `getX()` function) is copied over, as opposed to being instantiated in `Parent`'s constructor. Similarly, the `getX()` method itself is copied over with it's `this` referencing the old parent (because it is a fat arrow function, the `this` reference does not change).

The most straightforward way to fix this is to add a copy constructor to `Parent` and use that instead of the spread syntax:

```js
export class Parent {
    properties: { x: string};
    child: Child;
    constructor(source?: Parent) {
        this.properties = {
            x: '1'
        }

        this.child = new Child(() => this.getX());

        if (source) {
            this.properties = {...source.properties};
            // any additional copy logic goes here
        }
    }

    getX() {
        return this.properties.x;
    }
}
```

Then use that copy constructor in your component:

```js
    const incrementX = () => {
        let newParent = new Parent(parent);
        newParent.properties.x = newParent.properties.x + 1;
        setParent(newParent);
    }
```

Note that an even easier solution would be to not copy the original `Parent` at all, and just increment its `properties.x`, but I'm assuming you need a new instance for the state change to be detected.